# Appearance settings broken in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: settings, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 one week ago.

Somehow, I had no settings when I first launched my newly upgraded Ubuntu. I managed to fix that after installing gnome-control-center.

Everything works fine except the "Appearance" settings. I can't change my theme nor enable my dock. The dock is kept hidden for some reason (even though this option is disabled by default). I don't use tweak or any other packages for the dock or the appearance of my windows.

I couldn't find any way to fix it. I tried to remove the user file in dconf or even the .config directory but none of these worked.

Is there anything I could do to fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: This was helpful for me: `sudo apt install tasksel` then `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop` then `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 10):

Try by reinstalling the gnome control center:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I have about the same issue. The 3 proposed theme in the Appearance theme dont click and all look not active. 
But `sudo apt install gnome-control-center` does nothing because it is uptodate.

Answer (score 3):

You have to re-install Gnome Control Center by typing these command lines:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by reinstalling the gnome control center:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

I got an error when changing show on, the value was constant allmonitors reinstalling fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from 16.04 LTS and had the same problem. The new theme (since 18.04?) seems to be [yaru](https://ubuntu.com/blog/new-ubuntu-theme-in-development-for-20-04), which was not installed in my configuration.

I installed these yaru packages, and theme switching in "appearance" worked again:

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-gnome-shell yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-unity yaru-theme-sound
```

Answer (score 1):

I am *not* sure what the problem is, but removing and re-installing the GUI could serve a purpose similar to a reboot (flush/rebuild):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>...) to switch to a TTY session, and run these:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Works fine after reboot, as it marked in comment to question